# Why does [ALT+224] return Ó instead of alpha?

Tags: ascii, ansi

I'm on WIN 7. I found that windows is using ANSI, not ASCII. So when I type <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>224</kbd> i get Ó, instead of α. To get α I have to manually copy it from the windows character map every time I want to use it. As you can imagine, this gets very tedious when I am trying to type in Attic Greek. Is there no combination to enter α? If not, is there some solution to this?

Comment: Do you want to type in greek?

Comment: I'm using windows and I get α.

Comment: Are you using WIN7? I might have been different on vista or xp.

Comment: @irikkkkk, what OS are you using?

Comment: @soandros, windows 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have already discovered, the characters resulting from character codes between `0` and `255` depend entirely on the encoding that is used.

*Windows* doesn't use neither extended ASCII nor ANSI (usually Windows-1252); it actually depends on the application.

For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>) gives on my machine:

- `α` in Notepad and on the command prompt.
- `à` in Google Chrome's omnibox, but `α` in its console and this very text area.
- In Notepad++, `a` with ANSI, `α` with UTF-8.

For a more consistent behavior, just use [Unicode character codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters):

The key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>) – or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>) if you set the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad` to `1` – **should** result in a `α` in every application that supports that character.

Sadly, that isn't the case:

- The decimal char code results in `▒` in IE's address bar, while the hexadecimal one just beeps.
- The decimal char code results in `▒` in Notepad++ with ANSI and `¦` with UTF-8.
- The hexadecimal char code results in `a` in Notepad++ with ANSI and `α` with UTF-8.

#### Summary

1. Set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad` to `1`.
2. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>) in applications with full Unicode support.
3. Fall back to trial and error in applications that lack full Unicode support.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing with a `0`? Ie. `ALT-0224` gives `à` consistently (here), but `ALT-224` gives `Ó` (position 224 in DOS-Western Europe code page). [I don't have the hexadecimal entry set.] As I understand it the zero prefix forces interpretation as a Unicode code point.

Comment: The `0` is used to indicate a Unicode character when the char code is ambiguous, which is only needed between `0` and `255` with our code pages (although `0` - `127` will **always** be ASCII). `[Alt] - 0945` will result in `±`: Since the `0` is out of place here, the application falls back to non-Unicode and wraps at `256` (i.e., `256` is congruent to `0`, `257` to `2`, etc.). `±` char code is `177`, where `945 = 3 * 256 + 177`.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that worked for me.

Initially, the "Current language for non-Unicode programs" was set to "English (United Kingdom)" on the computer in `Region → Administrative settings`; however, when I changed it to "English (United States)" and restarted the computer.

I finally started to get "α" when I hit Alt 224. No more "Ó". I've attached an image of the settings location.

[image: Fixed Alt 224 problem]