# Hyphen is not rendering in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++, unicode, utf-8

I'm sure this is an encoding issue, but I can't figure it out.

I exported a spreadsheet from Excel as a UTF-8 CSV. This produced a CSV in the UTF-8-BOM character encoding. Opening this file in Notepad++, most of the characters were rendered correctly - including non ANSI characters like `ø`. However, a hyphen ( `‐` ) is displayed as `☐`.

I believe the character is `U+2010 ‐ HYPHEN`.

If I open the file in [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), the hyphen displays correctly. It also displays correctly if I use [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) to read the file or `cat` to print it out to the terminal.

Finally, the octal dump of the file reveals the hex bytes `e2 80 90`, which is the UTF-8 encoding of the `U+2010 - HYPHEN` Unicode character.

So why is Notepad++ displaying this character as `☐`?

Comment: After opening the file, have you tried to change the encoding format?

Comment: Yep. Nothing works. The file is definitely saved as UTF-8-BOM, as proved by it working in regular notepad (and python, and vim, and cat)

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not the "common hyphen" that we have on our keyboards, which is `U+002D: HYPHEN-MINUS`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If other characters are being decoded properly and the byte-level data looks correct, it's possible the issue is just with the font. [U+2010](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128) is high up enough that some fonts might just not have a glyph available.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1271513) to [another Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/524619/how-do-i-enter-a-hyphen-not-a-minus-symbol-on-windows-7) states that a number of common Windows 7 fonts don't have the glyph for *HYPHEN*.

Comment: It is the font! Switching to `consolas`, used by regular notepad (and, indeed, stack exchange), solved the issue. Thanks!